# PrimeFaces Schedule component button javascript action

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem regarding primefaces schedule component buttons like the prev, next and also current date button. Can I put any function for the action of these buttons to get any value and also call another action?

```
function setSelectedFullDayBackground(selectedDate)
        {
            var weekendDate = new Date(selectedDate);
            $('td[data-date="' + weekendDate.toISOString().substr(0, 10) + '"]').addClass('fullDayBackground');
        }
```

I need a way to call this javascript method and the primefaces schedule component button.
I found some way to working with this, however when I try to use it, it did not working.

```
$('.fc-next-button').click(function () {
            console.info('test next');
        });

$('.fc-prev-button').click(function () {
            console.info('test prev');
        });
```

The console.info did not show at the browser. How to work with these buttons?

Comment: Are you sure he selectors are correct and the buttons exist when the click handlers are attached?

Comment: I use the button class name as shown in the dev tools. @Roamer-1888